# Store a numbers in stack and print it in queue

Tags: java

if i store a numbers in stack , and i want to print it in queue , should i store the same numbers in queue again to print it ,  or there is another way to do it ?

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Scanner ;

public class Qa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        Stack<Integer> A =new Stack<Integer>();

        System.out.println(" the numbers should be less than 99 ");
        int x =  input.nextInt() ; 

        while(x> 0 && x < 99){

             A.push(x);


        }

        PriorityQueue<String> B =new PriorityQueue<String>();


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Queue is basically FIFO. First store the elements in a Stack. Pop the elements and store it again in another Stack. Now pop the elements you will get it as FIFO(Queue).

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a List with the contents of the stack and then print from the List? You can print from last element in List till first

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what you specific want to do, but if you have the numbers stored, you don't need to re-store again. You can just reed them in from the [first-->last] or [last-->first].
An example with code is here:

- [CodeExample](http://buenasintencions.blogspot.com.ar/2011/12/archivo-invertirarreglo.html)

with that you save memory and time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is suppose that you utilizes the stack structure for some reason, but the results could be the same, storing data in a simple list, and then depending in what you wanna do, uses that list. You could save space and time, because doesn't be necessary duplicate data or make unnecessary loops on complex data structures.
Hope this helps.

Comment: i didn't use list because the Question says : Arrays, lists, API classes and any other data structures are not allowed :)

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Stack it is an ordered `Iterable` like a `List`. you can get the elements in order of insertion by iterating over the stack with a `for` loop (or `.forEach` in Java 8).

I'm pasting the example code and output below:

```
public class MyApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> myInts = new Stack<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      myInts.push(i);
    }

    System.out.println("ITERATING:");

    myInts.forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("\nPOPPING:");

    while(!myInts.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println(myInts.pop());
    }
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
ITERATING:
0
1
2
3
4

POPPING:
4
3
2
1
0
```

You see that if you iterate over the `Stack` it returns the numbers **in order of insertion**. If your intent is just print the contents of the stack this approach has the additional benefit of not having to mutate the stack by calling `pop()`.